# Is there a name for the database table that's the other side of a join table?

Tags: sql, documentation

I'm trying to write some documentation and can't think of a generic name for the table that's the other side of a join table.

Is there a specific name for it? If not, any ideas? 'joined table'?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're typically referred to as "left" and "right" tables.